# Is there a Python best practice for calling the same function with different parameter values?

Tags: python, docker

I'm trying to use the Python Docker SDK:

```
        if condition:
            container = _docker.containers.run(
                myimage,
                command = ...,
                volumes = ...,
                detach = ...,
                ports  = ...,
                .
                .
                .
            )
        else:
            container = _docker.containers.run(
                myimage,
                command = ...,
                volumes = ...,
                detach = ...,
                ports  = ...,
                .
                .
                .
            )
```

In other words, if a certain condition is met, I want to call run() with a certain set of parameters; else, call run() with a different set of parameters.

There a lot of parameters that change across the condition. Is there a more efficient way of writing this?

Comment: You can store the arguments in dictionaries and then use the dictionary unpack/"splat" operator to expand the dictionary and use its contents as keyword arguments like so `container = _docker.containers.run(**kwargs)` where `kwargs = {"image": myimage, "command": ...}`. In that case, you only have to edit the dictionary.

Comment: I don't think so.

you could use an array and a dict to store args and kwargs in, but the if statement will not be much easier.
If things are so different, then you have to code the difference.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `*args` for positional arguments and `**kwargs` for keyword arguments:

```
args = [myimage]
kwargs = {
    'command': ...,
    'volumes': ...,
    'detach': ...,
    'ports': ...,
}
if condition:
    .
    .
    .
else:
    .
    .
    .
container = _docker.containers.run(*args, **kwargs)
```